# Which artist had a special exhibition in the Kunstmuseum Bonn in summer 2012?

Tags: germany, cultural-history, art, contemporary-history, popular-culture

In the [Kunstmuseum Bonn](https://www.kunstmuseum-bonn.de/de/) in Summer 2012, I can remember there was a special exhibition on show about an (probably American) contemporary abstract expressionist artist who did graffiti like abstract art work with an organic, tube-like touch.

I would like to know his name but, unfortunately, don't have further information, except that he was inspired partially by Jackson Pollock.

Can you help me to find the name of the artist?

Comment: Yes, that's him, D. Reed. I recognize his style. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I searched "Kunstsmuseum Bonn 2012"; the museum publicity for that year is online, listing the artists and showing some thumbnails - that might help you to recall. Could it have been [D. Reed](https://museumpublicity.com/2012/06/28/kunst-museum-bonn-opens-david-reed-heart-of-glass-paintings-and-drawings-1967-2012/)